# Craftsman 1/2Hp belt garage door opener going past it up and down limits

Tags: garage-door-opener, motor

After replacing the old belt with a new one, I tried the opener and in the up position it went back towards the motor and tried going past the limit stud. The belt kept jumping on the motor sprocket. I unplugged the unit and started from scatch since I have the original manual. After going through the setup I get the same results in the down and up movement (belt jumping on the motor sprocket)
Craftsman 1/2Hp Model 139.53914D

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. You'll note this is a Question & Answer forum, not a Make Statements forum. Please [edit] your question to actually ask a question. The more detail you give us (including, maybe, some pics), the more likely we'll be able to help you quickly.

Comment: Why did you replace the belt? Was it doing this before you replaced the belt, and that damaged the original belt?

Comment: The belt connector where the link is placed frayed and snapped.
This required a new belt replacement, because the old one failed.